# how to print the contents of char**?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, char, c99

I have a structure defined as a char** array containing strings. I dont know how to run printf on its contents.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef STRUCT_STRING_ARRAY
#define STRUCT_STRING_ARRAY
typedef struct s_string_array
{
    int size;
    char** array;
} string_array;
#endif


void my_print_words_array(string_array* param_1)
{
    int len = param_1->size;
    char **d = param_1->array;


    for(int i = 0 ; i < len;i++){
        printf("%s\n", d[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    struct s_string_array *d;
    d->size = 2;

    char **my_arr = (char *[]){"hello", "world"};//this init is fine
    d->array = my_arr;
    my_print_words_array(d);
    return 0 ;

}
```

the main function gives me segfault error. What's wrong?

Comment: Where are you allocating memory for the struct?

Comment: No repro.  https://repl.it/@robertwharvey/LoathsomeCostlyReentrant

Comment: @RobertHarvey hi , u mean it works? no repro? you mean i should just put a link to executable online ide?

Comment: Well... I'm inclined to agree with Tony.  You're not allocating memory for `struct s_string_array *d;`

Comment: So it might be UB.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, wait, but i'm doing s->size = 2; you mean malloc? i should use malloc?

Comment: `struct s_string_array *d = malloc(sizeof(string_array));`

Comment: @RobertHarvey, just to clarify - malloc(sizeof(string_array)) - allocates memory needed for the entire struct? if there was no string_array in the definition of my struct - it would not know how to refer to the structure,right?

Comment: But there *is* a `string_array` in the definition of your struct.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, yes yes, but lets imagine there was no this little "string_array" what would i put in the malloc? malloc(struct s_string_array)?

Comment: Your malloc would not change.  It's allocating memory for the entire struct.  So whatever you're putting in that struct, that's what it will allocate memory for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no sense to declare a pointer to the structure

```
struct s_string_array *d;
```

moreover that is not initialized and has indeterminate value that further is a reason of undefined behavior.

What you are trying to achieve is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct s_string_array
{
    int size;
    char** array;
} string_array;

void my_print_words_array( const string_array *param_1 )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < param_1->size; i++ )
    {
        puts( param_1->array[i] );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    string_array d =
    {
        .size = 2,
        .array = (char *[]){"hello", "world"}
    };

    my_print_words_array( &d );

    return 0 ;

}
```

The program output is

```
hello
world
```

Comment: Good example of using `char **` _without_ using dynamic allocated memory.